# data overwriten when using checkbox

Tags: php

I have php code like this :

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['vehicles']))
    {
        $vehicles=$_POST['vehicles'];
        $hostname='localhost';
        $username='root';
        $password='root';
        $dbname='pet';
        $connect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname) or die("can't connect to server");
        $query="UPDATE information SET transportation='$vehicles'";
        $query=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can't execute query");
        echo "inserted";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "error";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "choose your vehicle";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Select transportation you have</title>
</head>
<body><h2>Select transportation you have</h2>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles" value="bike"/>I have bike<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles" value="car"/>I have car<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles" value="motor"/>I have motor<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

when i choose more than one options there is only one value in my database.For example i choose bike and motor.There is only motor in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the name of the inputs to be an array by add [] at the end of the name

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles[]" value="bike"/>I have bike<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles[]" value="car"/>I have car<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles[]" value="motor"/>I have motor<br/>
```

then in php you will be able to access them using the array syntax, and you can simply use `implode` to make a comma separated list of the vehicles.

```
$_POST['vehicles'][0]
$_POST['vehicles'][1]
$_POST['vehicles'][2]
//etc...

$vehicles = implode(",",$_POST['vheicles']);
$query="UPDATE information SET transportation='$vehicles'";
//$query would contain something like:
//UPDATE information SET transportation='bike,car'
```

Of course do sanitation on the POST variables before putting them in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the html to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles[]" value="bike"/>I have bike<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles[]" value="car"/>I have car<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicles[]" value="motor"/>I have motor<br/>
```

Change the PHP to:

```
$vehicles=implode(',',$_POST['vehicles']);
```

Comment: You forgot a `,` in implode: `implode(',', $_POST['vehicles']);`